# Safari: Autofill saves username but should save email

Tags: html, safari, autofill

I have the problem that Safari is saving the username to KeyChain but should save the email.

In the registration page I have three inputs:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="username"
    autocomplete="off"
    required
>

<input
    type="email"
    name="e-mail"
    autocomplete="email"
    required
>
<input
    type="password"
    name="pass_word"
    autocomplete="new-password"
    required
>
```

However, after the registration, Safari keychain saves the username not the email. How can I force it?

In my login page, I'm only accepting email addresses as the "username".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element).

I have to set email as username, then everything works.

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="username"
    required
>

<input
    type="email"
    name="e-mail"
    autocomplete="username"
    required
>
<input
    type="password"
    name="pass_word"
    autocomplete="new-password"
    required
>
```